# Multiple links in the same cell

Tags: excel-2010

I'm using excel 2010 and i have no idea how can i delete links delimited by ";" from the same cell. The cell is looking like this:

```
http://link/t/001/10_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/1_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/2_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/3_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/4_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/5_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/6_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/7_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/8_1.jpg;http://link/t/001/9_1.jpg
```

I need only 1 link, not all of them. How can i delete the other links?I have over 1.000.000 rows in this file so i can not do manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function "Text to columns". In the menu, select "Data" and "Text to Columns". In the first step, you must choose the option "Delimited" and in the second step you must configure the "Delimiters" as "Other". In this moment, you can fill the correspondent field with ";". The Excel will separate all links in columns and so you can delete the last ones.